# Manipulating data of Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a dataframe and trying to 'insert' a list inside another list and then converting it to json file. I'm using python 3 and 0.25.3 version of pandas for it.

**My dataframe:**

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer    part_number   number_client

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897           982

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          888            12

92    Hong Kong      CUST-88888         China           147            288
```

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
import json

data = pd.read_excel(path)

data["part_number"] = data["part_number"].apply(lambda x: str(x))
data["number_client"]  = data["number_client"].apply(lambda x: str(x))

data = data.groupby(["id", "label", "id_customer", "label_customer"], as_index=False).agg("#".join)

data["part_number"] = data["part_number"].apply(lambda x: {"part": x})
data["number_client"] = data["number_client"].apply(lambda x: {"client": x})

data["id_customer"] = data["id_customer"].apply(lambda x: {"id": x})
data["label_customer"] = data["label_customer"].apply(lambda x: {"label": x})
data["number"] = data.apply(lambda x: [{**x["part_number"], **x["number_client"]}], axis=1)

data["Customer"] = data.apply(lambda x: [{**x["id_customer"], **x["label_customer"], **data["number"]}],axis=1)

data = data[["id", "label", "Customer"]]

data.to_json(path)
```

**Json output I'm getting:**

```
[{
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Sao Paulo",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUST-99992",
        "label": "Brazil",
        "0": [{
            "part": "7897",
            "client": "982"
        }],
        "1": [{
            "part": "888",
            "client": "12"
        }],
        "2": [{
            "part": "147",
            "client": "288"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "label": "Sao Paulo",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUST-99992",
        "label": "Brazil",
        "0": [{
            "part": "7897",
            "client": "982"
        }],
        "1": [{
            "part": "888",
            "client": "12"
        }],
        "2": [{
            "part": "147",
            "client": "288"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "id": 92,
    "label": "Hong Kong",
    "Customer": [{
        "id": "CUST-888888",
        "label": "China",
        "0": [{
            "part": "7897",
            "client": "982"
        }],
        "1": [{
            "part": "888",
            "client": "12"
        }],
        "2": [{
            "part": "147",
            "client": "288"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

**What I need:**

```
 [{
      "id": 6,
      "label": "Sao Paulo",
        "Customer": [{
            "id": "CUST-99992",
            "label": "Brazil",
            "number": [{
                "part": "7897",
                "client": "982" 
            },
            {
                "part": "888",
                "client": "12"
            }]
        }]
    },
    {     
      "id": 92,
      "label": "Hong Kong",
        "Customer": [{
            "id": "CUST-888888",
            "label": "China",
            "number": [{
                "part": "147",
                "client": "288"
                }]
            }]
        }
    ]
```

Look that `id` and `label` a is group of information even as `id_customer` and `label_customer` is another group, `part_number` and `number_client` is another. `Customer`and `number` are lists and they can have a lot objects inside them (the number of objects depends of my data in my dataframe).

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Tks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First cast both columns to strings and then use lambda functions with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) and rename columns names, last convert output to json by [`DataFrame.to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html):

```
data[["part_number","number_client"]] = data[["part_number","number_client"]].astype(str)

f = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]

j =(data.groupby(["id","label","id_customer","label_customer"])['part_number','number_client']
        .apply(lambda x: x.rename(columns=f).to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='number')
        .groupby(["id", "label"])[ "id_customer", "label_customer", "number"]
        .apply(lambda x: x.rename(columns=f).to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='customer')
        .to_json(orient='records'))
```

---

```
print (j)

    [{
        "id": 6,
        "label": "Sao Paulo",
        "customer": [{
            "id": "CUST-99992",
            "label": "Brazil",
            "number": [{
                "part": "7897",
                "number": "982"
            }, {
                "part": "888",
                "number": "12"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "id": 92,
        "label": "Hong Kong",
        "customer": [{
            "id": "CUST-88888",
            "label": "China",
            "number": [{
                "part": "147",
                "number": "288"
            }]
        }]
    }]
```

Comment: Tks @jezrael.. solved the problem!! Just one question.. i'd like to change `part` key to `part_my_client` in my Json... but `lambda` function split when I use `_`. What should I change in the code??

Comment: @LucasTerwistz - I think simpliest is change function for `rename` - `f = lambda x: x.split('_')[0] if x != 'part_number' else 'part_my_client_number'`

Comment: I got something @jezrael... if my content is the same in row 0 and row 1... the code is duplicating the objects inside number list (wrong behaviour)..

Comment: @Lucas Terwistz Is possible create new question? Thanks.

Comment: For sure @jezreal.. Done -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276102/manipulating-data-of-a-dataframe-in-pandas .. Could you help me?