# Manipulating data of a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a dataframe and converting it into a json file. I'm using python 3 and 0.25.3 version of pandas for it. I already got some help from you guys ([Manipulating data of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59268800/manipulating-data-of-pandas-dataframe)), but I have some questions about the code and how it works.

**My dataframe:**

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer    part_number   number_client

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897           982

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          888            12

92    Hong Kong      CUST-88888         China           147            288
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_excel(path)

data[["part_number","number_client"]] = data[["part_number","number_client"]].astype(str)

f = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]

j =(data.groupby(["id","label","id_customer","label_customer"])['part_number','number_client']
        .apply(lambda x: x.rename(columns=f).to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='Number')
        .groupby(["id", "label"])[ "id_customer", "label_customer", "Number"]
        .apply(lambda x: x.rename(columns=f).to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='Customer')
        .to_json(orient='records'))

print (j)
```

**Json I'm getting:**

```
[{
        "id": 6,
        "label": "Sao Paulo",
        "Customer": [{
            "id": "CUST-99992",
            "label": "Brazil",
            "number": [{
                    "part": "7897",
                    "client": "982"
                },
                {
                    "part": "888",
                    "client": "12"
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 92,
        "label": "Hong Kong",
        "Customer": [{
            "id": "CUST-888888",
            "label": "China",
            "number": [{
                "part": "147",
                "client": "288"
            }]
        }]
    }
]
```

**1st Question:**  `lambda` and `apply` function are spliting my columns' name when a `_` is found.. That is just a piece of my dataframe and some columns I'd like to preserve the name.. e.g: I want get `part_number` and `number_client` instead `part` and `client` in my json structure. How can I fix this?

**2nd Question:** I can have different lists with the same key name. E.g: In `customer` list I have `part_number` key, but I can also have the same name of key inside another list with another value. E.g: `part_number` inside `test` list.

**3rd Question:** In my complete dataframe, I have a column called `Additional_information` when I have a simple text. I have to get a structure like this:

```
...

"Additional_information":[{
        {
          "text": "testing",
        }
        },
        {
         "text": "testing again",
        }
        ]
```

for a dataframe like this:

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer    part_number   number_client    Additional_information

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897           982           testing

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897           982           testing again
```

What should I change?

Comment: There is no "pt. 2" on Stack Overflow. It might be a follow-up from a previous question, and it's fine (probably good) to link to a previous question, but there is no concept of continuity between questions; they should be self-contained in a way that they can be sufficiently addressed in isolation

Comment: I didn't know that @roganjosh.. I already changed my question title.. Tks a lot for your comment..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st Question:**

You can write custom function for rename, e.g. like:

```
def f(x):
    vals = ['part_number', 'number_client']
    if x in vals:
        return x
    else:
        return x.split('_')[0]
```

**2nd Question**

If I understand correctly keys in final json are created from columns of original Dataframe, and also by parameter `name` by `reset_index` of my solution. If want some another logic for change keys (columns names) is possible change first solution.

**3rd Question**

In original solution is changed `to_json` to `to_dict` for possible modify final list of dict like append `text` info, for json is used `json.dumps` in last step:

```
import json

def f(x):
    vals = ['part_number', 'number_client']
    if x in vals:
        return x
    else:
        return x.split('_')[0]

d =(data.groupby(["id","label","id_customer","label_customer"])['part_number','number_client']
        .apply(lambda x: x.rename(columns=f).to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='Number')
        .groupby(["id", "label"])[ "id_customer", "label_customer", "Number"]
        .apply(lambda x: x.rename(columns=f).to_dict('r')).reset_index(name='Customer')
        .to_dict(orient='records'))

#print (d)

d1 = (data[['Additional_information']].rename(columns={'Additional_information':'text'})
                                      .to_dict(orient='records'))
d1 = {'Additional_information':d1}
print (d1)
{'Additional_information': [{'text': 'testing'}, {'text': 'testing again'}]}

d.append(d1)
#print (d)

j = json.dumps(d)
#print (j)
```